# What is this white component in this emergency light?

Tags: led, sensor, light

I have an emergency light, which I opened up. I see there is a yellow cable going to that sot of electronic component (by 'L+'). Is this a light sensor?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any solderpad to the right, or beneath, or just one single pad?

Comment: @MiNiMe there is a solder pad to the right, underneath it.

Comment: Measured the resistance at various light?

Comment: Is it a (red) standby indicator LED?  (Does it illuminate?)

Comment: If it is a photodiode (which is very likely), you can measure a couple microamps across the diode when exposed to light.

Comment: It look like an IR LED used to actuate a photodiode. See of ot faces a photodiode when everything is assembled.  The photodiode can be as small as the LED.